# Cesium: Move camera to view entity if not visible

Tags: cesiumjs

I want to make sure that an entity is always visible but it doesn't have to be in the center of the view (thus I couldn't use `trackedEntity`). In other words – let the entity move (it's a `SampledPositionProperty`) in the current view, let the user zoom and move the view as they wish but if the entity moves away from the view (or the user moves the view from the entity) then center the view around the entity once.

In Google Maps API, this is trivial:

```js
if (!map.getBounds().contains(latLng)) {
  map.setCenter(latLng);
}
```

I couldn't find a similar API in Cesium and I think that I must be missing something obvious. I've tried `Entity.isShowing` but it doesn't care about the camera view.

Comment: This is in 2D view. I'm not sure if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually quite easy. What got me confused is using different objects (`Cartesian3` or `Cartographic`) in different functions. This is my code:

```js
// lat, lng, height defined
const cartographic = Cesium.Cartographic.fromDegrees(lng, lat, height);
if (!Cesium.Rectangle.contains(map.camera.computeViewRectangle(), cartographic)) {
  const destination = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(lng, lat, height);
  map.camera.flyTo({destination, duration: .5});
}
```